# Use of Multithreading in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am not a trained and professional programmer.

My VB.net program displays a dialog box and collects data from the user. It then opens another application and adds this data to a document in that application.

Since opening of the other Application takes time and my program has to wait for considerable amount of time, I was thinking if multithreading can help.

1. Start program.
2. Open the Application using a thread.
3. While the application is opening, display the form and collect data from the user.
4. After User click OK button, make sure that the Application is open and only then start adding the collected data to the document in the application document.

I would appreciate if somebody can guide me.

Comment: Winform application running on thread.

Comment: It doesn't help, it will take just as long.  "Guide me" is not a question, you have to ask an answerable question at this site.

Comment: You should at least show how you are opening the other application. Maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to go is to use a BackgroundWorker. It hides the details of the multithreading problematic. There is a good description for VB here: [The Background Worker](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/88605-the-background-worker/)